# Vue Router: hide parent template when child is open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im trying to install Vue.js with the router and im running into some view issues. I have a `router.js` with child routes. I want to use this method for simple breadcrumbs and generate a clear overview so i know which route belongs where.

Opening each route works like a charm, everything shows up. When i open `/apps` I get a nice view from my `Apps.vue` that displays `App overview</h1>`. But now im opening `/apps/app-one` and then I see the `Apps.vue` and `AppOne.vue` template. How can I prevent that both templates are displayed?

The vue components looks like this:

#### Router.js

```
import Router from 'vue-router';
import AppsPage from './components/Apps.vue'
import AppOne from './components/AppOne.vue'
import AppTwo from './components/AppTwo.vue'

export default new Router({
    // mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/apps',
            component: AppsPage,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/apps/app-one',
                    component: AppOne,
                },
                {
                    path: '/apps/app-two',
                    component: AppTwo,
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
});
```

#### Apps.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app-overview">
        <h1>App overview</h1>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app_page'
    }
</script>
```

#### App1.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>App 1</h1>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'app_one'
}
</script>
```

#### App2.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>App 2</h1>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'app_two'
}
</script>
```

Comment: If it is so, then it's absolutely fine, parent component should be present in child component. If you don't want make it as another route.

Comment: Isnt it possible to prevent the parent to be in the child?

Comment: Remove `<router-view></router-view>` from parent and create routes independently.

Answer (score 13):

Having your routes in a parent-child relationship means that the child component will be rendered inside the parent component (at the `<router-view>`). This is expected behavior.

If you do not want the parent component to be visible when the child route is active, then the routes should be siblings, not nested:

```
[
    {
        path: '/apps',
        component: AppsPage,
    },
    {
        path: '/apps/app-one',
        component: AppOne,
    },
    {
        path: '/apps/app-two',
        component: AppTwo,
    },
]
```

The structure of the routes reflects the way they are rendered on the page.

Comment: Also there is no use to include `<router-view>` inside parent, I think.

Comment: Yep, `<router-view>` is only needed to render child route components, if there are none then it's unnecessary.

Comment: nested on desktop, sibling on mobile how to do this, its for a master detail layout

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and pretty easy too.You can achieve this by followings:

```
<template>

    <div>

        <div v-show="isExactActive">
            Parent component contents will be here
        </div>

        <router-view ref="rv"></router-view>

    </div>

</template>


<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                isExactActive: true,
            }
        },

        updated() {
            this.isExactActive = typeof this.$refs.rv === 'undefined';
        },

        mounted() {
            this.isExactActive = typeof this.$refs.rv === 'undefined';
        }

    }
</script>
```

Hope, this will be helpful.